# Spark - Mapping columns to variables in JAVA from an RDD or DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to map cassandra row columns in a Spark RDD to variables that I can interate over for manipulation within spark but can't seem to get them into a variable.  I have the following code:

```
JavaRDD<MeasuredValue> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("model", "reports", mapRowTo (MeasuredValue.class))
   .select("start_frequency","bandwidth", "power");


    JavaRDD<Value> valueRdd = rdd.flatMap(row-> {
        double start_frequency = row.getStartFrequency();
        float power = row.getPower();
        double bandwidth = row.getBandwidth(); 


        List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>();
     // Create Channel Power Buckets    
        for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end;  ){ 
            if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) {     
             list.add(new Value(channel, power));
            }  // end if
            channel+=increment;
        }  // end for      

    })
```

My Classes Look like this:

```
public class Value implements Serializable {
    public Value(Double channel, Float power) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.power = power;
    }
    Double channel;
    Float power;

    public void setChannel(Double channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
    public void setPower(Float power) {
        this.power = power;
    }
    public Double getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
    public Float getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +channel +","+power+"]";
    }
}

public static class MeasuredValue implements Serializable {

        public MeasuredValue() { }

        private double start_frequency;
        public double getStart_frequency() { return start_frequency; }
        public void setStart_frequency(double start_frequency) { this.start_frequency = start_frequency; }

        private double bandwidth ;
        public double getBandwidth() { return bandwidth; }
        public void setBandwidth(double bandwidth) { this.bandwidth = bandwidth; }

        private float power;    
        public float getPower() { return power; }
        public void setPower(float power) { this.power = power; }

    }
```

My attempt at trying to flatmap the row with a lambda seems to be wrong since I'm getting an error of:

> method flatMap in class AbstractJavaRDDLike cannot be applied
>   to given types; required: FlatMapFunction found:
>   (row)->{d[...];}} reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U (argument
>   mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression missing return value)

I'm getting errors in the "Create Channel Power Bucket" loop about

> "local variable referenced from a lambda expression must be final
>   or effectively final"

If I can do this with a DataFrame instead I'd be interested in seeing code to facilitate that.

Comment: Should I be using a DataFrame instead of an RDD?

Comment: The second error message suggests that some variables used within lambda are not declared final - what are `increment` and `channel_end` variables? Are they `final`?

Comment: They are defined as follows:  `// Define Variable
    double channel,channel_end,start_frequency, increment, bandwidth;
    float power;
    long time_key;
    
// Initialize Variables
    channel_end = 1.6159E8;
    increment = 5000;
    `

Comment: Well then that's it (or part of it) - they must be made final, e.g. `final double channel_end = 1.6159E8;`

Comment: The main issue is being able to map the row Column values to variables.  That I can manipulate from within spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer Discovered to be:**

```
JavaRDD<MeasuredValue> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("SB1000_47130646", "Measured_Value", mapRowTo(MeasuredValue.class));
JavaRDD<Value> valueRdd = rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<MeasuredValue, Value>(){
@Override 
public Iterable<Value> call(MeasuredValue row) throws Exception { 
double start_frequency = row.getStart_frequency(); 
float power = row.getPower(); 
double bandwidth = row.getBandwidth(); 

// Define Variable 
double channel,channel_end, increment;  

// Initialize Variables 
channel_end = 1.6159E8; 
increment = 5000; 

List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(); 
// Create Channel Power Buckets 
for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end; ){ 
if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) { 
list.add(new Value(channel, power)); 
} // end if 
channel+=increment; 
} // end for 

return list; 
}    
    });

    sqlContext.createDataFrame(valueRdd, Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
    .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
    .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
    .option("table", "results")
    .option("keyspace", "model")
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();

} // end session
} // End Compute 

public class Value implements Serializable {
    public Value(Double channel, Float power) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.power = power;
    }
    Double channel;
    Float power;

    public void setChannel(Double channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
    public void setPower(Float power) {
        this.power = power;
    }
    public Double getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
    public Float getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +channel +","+power+"]";
    }
}

public static class MeasuredValue implements Serializable {

        public MeasuredValue() { }

        private double start_frequency;
        public double getStart_frequency() { return start_frequency; }
        public void setStart_frequency(double start_frequency) { this.start_frequency = start_frequency; }

        private double bandwidth ;
        public double getBandwidth() { return bandwidth; }
        public void setBandwidth(double bandwidth) { this.bandwidth = bandwidth; }

        private float power;    
        public float getPower() { return power; }
        public void setPower(float power) { this.power = power; }

    }
```